# Starting libvirt while kickstart install RHEL7

Tags: kvm-switch, libvirt, kickstart

I've a very problematic task, and one point makes me mad. I'll make is simple:
Goal: Install CentOS7 with kickstart. At the end of the install as post script, it should start libvirtd and create a virtual machine with virt-install command.

In my kickstart file I have:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/lib/libvirt/images/fw.qcow2 bs=1024 count=0 seek=10G
/usr/sbin/libvirtd -d &
systemctl enable libvirtd
virt-install --name=firewall --disk path=/var/lib/libvirt/images/fw.qcow2 --ram=2048 --vcpus=2 --nographics --os-type=linux --os-variant=rhel7 --location /mnt/cdrom/CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1511.iso --extra-args="console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200 rd_NO_PLYMOUTH"
```

However my experience is:
I don't know if it starts libvirt, it definelty enables it because after restart, libvirt is running, but the OS is not installed via virt-install. In the ks-post.log file, i have:

```
ERROR Cannot recv data: Connection reset bypeer
error: Dailed to connect to the hypervisor
error: no calid connection
error: Failed to connect socket to '/var/run/libvirt/libvirt-sock': No such file or directory
```

I assume I couldn't start libvirtd properly with the

> /usr/sbin/libvirtd -d &

command am I?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
/usr/sbin/libvirtd -d &
```

Try:

```
systemctl start libvirtd
```

You could use `journalctl` to look at the systemd logs.

Also, I wonder about your `--location` argument.

Comment: Already tried, but then I get the Running in chroot, ignoring request.

Comment: Ah, that's why you're trying to start it that way.  I saw some references to "firstboot" as an option, and http://askubuntu.com/questions/156771/run-a-script-only-at-the-very-first-boot

Comment: The location argument must be working. Reason why I state this if I execute this command after the installation is completed, then the virtual guest is ready to go. I've noticed in the meanwhile that nested virtualization wasn't enabled on my computer. As soon as I can, I'll restart it with "kvm-intel.nested=1" in my grub and see if it makes something different or not.

Comment: But I might just create a selfdestruct script for the 1st boot. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late, but for everyone wishing to do something similar in future, I suggest you make a `systemd` service which just executes a normal shell script containing your commands. A key difference between executing commands in chroot environment in Kickstart and normal booted up OS is that the kernel of the target machines is not loaded into execution (I don't know exactly) but as the services are not running (including all daemons) you will not be able to start any '`service`' or '`systemctl`' services in the kickstart chrooted environment. I faced a similar problem, and simply made a systemd file for my centos7 environment which after the initial reboot of the system, starts an apache server on port 8080 and copy-pastes a few custom files, and after execution deletes the original systemd file so that the same shell script isn't called after the first reboot.

NOTE: for this technique to work, you will have to copy paste the `systemd` and (if required) some other few files from the installation media (iso) to the destination filesystem. If you don't wish to do that, than in the chroot environment of your kickstart itself you can simply have it `curl` or `wget` (download) the systemd file into the systemd folder which are hosted on the same or another server.